# Access Core PHP folder inside a Laravel 8 project

Tags: php, laravel, routes, http-status-code-404

Laravel Project is installed in my root directory and I have another project inside root directory with Core PHP ,

[image]

COREPHP-PROJECT is the one I want to access , but every time I try to access example.com/COREPHP-PROJECT it's giving me 404 error.
I have tried more than 50 solutions from internet and nothing is working so far.
What I'm doing wrong here?

**NOTE: .htaccess file is renamed as I wanted to test without it too.**

Comment: well the document root for the site is supposed to be pointing to the `public` folder of the application so everything above that folder is not accessible .....

Comment: A good lesson from this is not to install two things in one location...keep applications separate from each other. If you need them to respond to certain URLs, adjust your webserver config accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is actually fine to have a project directory inside the applications root directory. A good application should not be build inside the framework. It should be build with the framework. If in 5 years somehow laravel is not anymore supported you can decouple it more easy and use it in a new framework.
You just need to assign the path to your composer.json under the psr-4 part.

```
 "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "MainApplication\\": "app/",
        "CorePhpProject\\": "CORE-PHP-PROJECT/app/",
```

But you should only route over the Laravel router.
You can add your routes inside laravels RouteServiceProvider.php
Have a look at the documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#the-default-route-files

Should look something like this then:

```
      Route::prefix('coreproject')
            ->group(base_path('CORE-PHP-PROJECT/routes/web.php'));
```

Then you can call your laravel routes like this
/home
and the project one are called like /coreproject/home

Answer (score 0):

I got into same task of integrating core php folder inside laravel , therefore solution i found that create a core php file with extension test.php in public folder at laravel root, and try to access in browser after php artisan serve, you will find you can access it.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32343856)